# JavaScript working with constructor

Tags: javascript, object, private

I have the following script included on my page (myScript.js).

```
   function constr(args) {
        var param1 = args;

        function drawTable(element, tableRows) {
           // code that creates table with rows = tableRows and appends table to the passed element
        }

        drawContainer(); // call to and extended functionality
    }

var obj = new constr(10);
```

But then I need the obj to be extended by some other private methods. Those methods will be loaded from another script (myScript2.js) and some of them have to override some private methods in constr. Also extended methods should be able to work work with param1 and other private variables in constr. Ideally everything will be private.

In myScript2.js
I should have something like

```
constr.prototype = (function() {
   return {
     constructor:constr,
     drawContainer: function() {
         var container = document.createElement("DIV");

         document.append(container);
         drawTable(container, param1);
     }
   }
})();
```

By doing the following prototype I assume to extend constr function by another private class - "drawContainer", and be able to call drawTable from original constr function with access to param1.

The following example wont work.
The idea of why I'm doing it is that I want to have a module of some js object that is loading extra functionality to the page when needed.

Comment: You're getting it all wrong. Even from a classical OOP perspective, private methods wouldn't be very private if you could overwrite them...

Comment: @MaxMandarenko—You should read Douglas Crockford's [Private Members in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html). @Iqc—you can have privileged functions that access and modify private members (see the linked article).

Comment: There might be a possible solution, but please post your actual code (including public, privileged methods) and also how you want to extend them.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but why are you declaring `param1` when you already have the perfectly good "local" variable `args`?